# authorize and capture - can't find fee info

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

What are the fees when using authorize and capture?
For regular payment I think the fee is 3.4% + 0.30$

Is that works the same way for authorize and capture?
Is there also fee for re-authorize?
Is there also fee for void?
Is there additional fee for multiple captures?

What happens if I did authorization for 500$ but eventually captured only 100$? the 3.9% are deducted from 500$ or 100$?

I know it's a lot of questions but hopefully I can get some answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PayPal account payments all fees are the same whether using auth/capture or not. Feed apply to captures, no auth fees, so in your example you would pay fees on $100, not $500.

But this type of info should be easily (and more reliably) obtained from PayPal's website or sales staff.

Answer (score 0):

PayPay charge fee only on the money they take - so no fee for authorize and fee only for the amount that was captured.